# Easy Admin - Display Full Country Name in Show Action

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin, easyadmin

I have an Address entity which requires a country. In the associated form I am using Symfony's CountryType which displays a user-friendly selection of countries and stores its abbreviation in the entity (e.g. DE for Germany or CH for Switzerland).

To display the address' country in the show action of the admin panel, I am using the following line in the `easy_admin.yaml`:

```
- { property: country, label: 'address.entity.country' }
```

**Problem:**

This only displays the abbreviation and not the actual name of the country. How can I change that?

**Country in Address entity:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $country;
```

Comment: can you please paste entity class of addrss?

Comment: Nothing special about the entity class itself as it only stores the country's abbreviation as a string. I added the country attribute above.

Comment: brother i want to see your __toString method?

Comment: Why would I need a toString method? I'm showing the content of the country attribute, not the address class itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to use the built in [Symfony intl component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html).

`composer require symfony/intl` to install the component.

Then in your entity you can `use Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl;`.

I suggest creating a new property on your entity called countryName where the setter of that property gets called whenever you set the country code. Your setter could look something like this:

```
public function setCountryName (string $countryCode) 
{
    $this->countryName = Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryName(strtoupper($countryCode));
}
```

Then in your `yaml` file change `address.entity.country` to `address.entity.countryName`.

Comment: No need for a setter, instead it's way simpler to just create `EntityName::getLocalizedCountry()` that would return the Intl you added in your code snippet and use `$this->country` from the entity :)

Comment: But would you be able to use that function in the `yaml` file of easy admin?

Answer (score 0):

I think now using `Intl::getRegionBundle()` is deprecated, the best will be to use the `Countries` class of the `Intl` component of symfony in this way :

```php
use Symfony\Component\Intl\Countries;

public function getCountryName ():string
{
    return Countries::getName($this->getCountry());
}
```